# would browsing in private mode skew location services data?

Tags: iphone

Recently started noticing a weird location on my  husbands iPhone at odd hours--saying he was in a location across town when he was literally sitting in front of me--it is same location every time.  would switching to private or incognito browsing cause that to happen?

Answer (score 2):

The Wifi location database is created by driving round, street to street, city to city, country to country, testing what WiFi can be 'seen' & mapping it to GPS locations.
None of this requires any login to the WiFi, merely noting where it is located.

This can take a while ;)

In the meantime, someone might move house, from one district to another, & take their WiFi with them. This will confuse the geo-locators until the next time the Wifi guy drives past again.

Alternatively, an ISP may assign a new IP address to a residence's connection - one outside their usual numeric range. This will produce the same effect.
My ISP recently did this here & I "moved" from London to Bristol for 2 weeks, whenever I was in the house, picking up my own home WiFi.

Comment: Its puzzling because it shows all the right locations for home, for work etc--but it will show this same location across town for an hour or two--usually late at night --but he is right here beside me the entire time. then it will return to correct home location. I can't figure it out

Comment: Pushing my scenario to its limit. Someone near you recently moved from there; only switch their WiFi on for a couple of hours a night. At that time, the phone can see it in the list of nearby devices & it triggers the move. [Not claiming it's true, but it's possible ;)

Comment: I do know that most of the times that are attributed to the incorrect location are when he is using his iPhone to browse the internet--I guess my hunch is that he uses private mode--could that cause the location services to be wrong?